# Add a link to /revisions from the timeline

Tags: feature-request, revisions-list, timeline

Recently (relatively), a link to the timeline was added on every post, allowing for a more convenient way to see the information presented there (such as reviews and a clear timeline of actions and responses).

However, there are certain things that are shown in the revision history that aren't shown in the timeline - most notably, questions entering HNQ or being automatically Tweeted.

If there are no, well, *revisions* to the post, there's no easily accessible link to the revision history of a post - which means if, for instance, I want to check if something had entered HNQ, I have to manually type in the /revisions URL (or use a userscript) to get there.

It would logically make sense, I believe, to put a link to the revision history from the timeline (and vice versa) - or even make it a tab like the old "Tools | Reviews" switcher used to be for easily switching back and forth.

At any rate, **could we please have a link to the revision history from the timeline of a post**?

Comment: I'm looking now, and it looks like questions entering HNQ are recorded in the timeline. This behavior is expected, as is tweets showing up there. It also shows edits. With the new timeline view, I'm not sure what value the revisions page has anymore. Perhaps it's easier to see the edit history and only the edit history of a question.

Comment: @ThomasOwens - Huh. They hadn't last I checked. Do you happen to have a link?

Comment: I used https://movies.stackexchange.com/posts/108922/timeline since it was in my HNQ. I'd have to find a tweeted post as I don't follow any of the SE twitter accounts. Honestly, there's just a lot of overlap now between timeline and revision, since revision does contain more than just revisions. Not sure what the right solution is, though.

Comment: @ThomasOwens revisions is easier to read, in my opinion at least. Better leave them both, and add links on both ends, i.e. link to revisions in timeline, and to timeline in the revisions page.